# Fb.ui method feed not working. Loading gif appears but no error message or anything

Tags: facebook, fb.ui

So I've been trying to implement a Fb method feed so that people can share songs from my website. But it doesn't work.

It pops up a loading gif in the dialogue and thats it. No error nothing. I've wasted a lot of time trying to figure this out but haven't been able to.

Here's the code,

```
share_obj = {     method: 'feed',
                      link: "", redirect_uri: "",
                      picture: ",
                      name: "",
                      caption:"" ,
                      description: ""
            }; FB.ui({method: "permissions.request", "perms": 'publish_stream'}, 
    callBack);
        function callBack(response) { if(response["perms"]=="publish_stream") { var obj = share_obj; FB.ui(obj,callback_share); } } function callback_share(response) { }
```

Does it have something to do with Facebook app migrations or app permissions?

Answer (score 0):

So turns out, there s no need to ask for user permissions when invoking the Fb.ui method.
Permissions are only required when you intend to publish stories via the graph API.